# Add pre-defined parameter to all routes

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I have an app that has tons of routes and controllers. Our app allows people to create projects and manage them. All of the routes except user related ones requires the project id, currently we store the project id in cookie but plan to move it to urls so the scheme will become  `/PROJECT_ID/project-related-endpoint` from `/project-related-endpoint`

I basically need to add a prefix to all my routes that represents the current project id but it requires too much work. All of the routes need to change, all redirection calls (`$location.path()`) needs to be re-written so I'm looking for a solid way to solve this problem. Should I override `$location.path()` that adds the prefix automatically and change the routes manually or is there any better way to handle this problem?

Comment: You currently store this main param in a cookie which sounds good to me. Now you want to append it to all routes but you also dont want to append  it to all routes because its to much work. This sounds ironic to me. Whats wrong by storing it in a cookie?

Comment: @lin I can't apply it to all routes because not all routes are related with project. For example; register, login, user password change and recover passwords pages don't require a project id. The main problem with storing the project ids in cookie is that when a user shares an url to other person, the selected project in other users browser may be different and this case causes some problems in our app. The other problem is that it's not possible to manage two different projects in a same browser window because the cookies will be shared.

Comment: 1) Could be easily solved by creating a unique route just for sharing like `http://myapp/sharing/project/:id`. 2) Could be easily solved by using `$rootScope` like `$rootScope = selectedProjectId` instead of cookies. right?

Comment: People usually just copy the link from the browser instead of looking for a share bar inside the webpage. Also the convention is using the project is in URL for most of the web applications, isn't it @lin?

Comment: Yep, I totally agree to this =). So, this discussion should take longer than search and adjustyour routes `/:projectId` + search and replace `$cookies.get('projectId')` with `$state.param.projectId` =)